# For Google Cloud's debian repository, which distribution corresponds to Debian Testing (currently, Trixie)?

Tags: debian, apt, deb, google-cloud, google

On Debian Testing (currently called Trixie), I would like to install the `google-cloud-cli` and `google-cloud-sdk-gke-gcloud-auth-plugin` packages that Google Cloud offers through its debian (package archive) repository [packages.cloud.google.com/apt/](https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/). But **which *(package archive) distribution* is the correct one to use?**

In their official documentation, Google Cloud [instructs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install#deb) to use the `cloud-sdk` distribution, regardless of the Debian version that it is running:

```
deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/cloud.google.gpg] http://packages.cloud.google.com/apt cloud-sdk main
```

But I'm hesitating to just use it because when we take a look at [packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists](https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists), we can see a long list of distributions that are specific to Debian versions. There is even a distribution specific to unstable/sid; but there is no distribution specific to testing/trixie:

```
cloud-sdk
cloud-sdk-artful
cloud-sdk-artful-unstable
cloud-sdk-bionic
cloud-sdk-bionic-unstable
cloud-sdk-bookworm
cloud-sdk-bullseye
cloud-sdk-bullseye-unstable
cloud-sdk-buster
cloud-sdk-buster-unstable
cloud-sdk-cosmic
cloud-sdk-cosmic-unstable
cloud-sdk-disco
cloud-sdk-disco-unstable
cloud-sdk-internal-testing
cloud-sdk-internal-testing-unstable
cloud-sdk-jessie
cloud-sdk-jessie-unstable
cloud-sdk-precise
cloud-sdk-precise-unstable
cloud-sdk-sid
cloud-sdk-sid-unstable
cloud-sdk-stretch
cloud-sdk-stretch-unstable
cloud-sdk-trusty
cloud-sdk-trusty-unstable
cloud-sdk-unstable
cloud-sdk-utopic
cloud-sdk-utopic-unstable
cloud-sdk-vivid
cloud-sdk-vivid-unstable
cloud-sdk-wheezy
cloud-sdk-wheezy-unstable
cloud-sdk-wily
cloud-sdk-wily-unstable
cloud-sdk-xenial
cloud-sdk-xenial-unstable
cloud-sdk-yakkety
cloud-sdk-yakkety-unstable
cloud-sdk-zesty
cloud-sdk-zesty-unstable
```

So, given these circumstances, which distribution is the correct one to use? Also, should I report a bug to Google Cloud?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The appropriate suite is the suite specified in the documentation, `cloud-sdk`.

If you look at the various `Packages` files available in the directories under https://packages.cloud.google.com/apt/dists, you’ll see that they reference the same packages in the pool; there is no practical distinction between suites. This isn’t surprising, since all the binaries are statically-linked Go binaries — there’s no need to account for differences between distributions or releases.

Generally speaking, when the suite *does* matter, you should look or a repository matching your distribution (*i.e.* Debian, not Ubuntu), and a release as close as possible to yours. Currently for Trixie that means either Bookworm (since Trixie is still fairly close to Bookworm) or Sid (since Trixie is a filtered Sid); in both cases there can be circumstances in which a package might not be installable, but `apt` should prevent you from actually breaking your system. *Don’t* add another release of Debian itself to satisfy dependencies unless you really know what you’re doing.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you by coincidence happen to know which distribution is the correct one to use for download.docker.com/linux/debian, for installing docker(-ce and -ce-cli), on Debian Testing/Trixie?

Comment: I’ve added a more general section which should allow you to figure that out.